# How to center AttributedText link in UITextView swift4

Tags: ios, swift4

Is there any way I can just make the text center and change the size/font?

I set it in storyboard but nothing happen when I ran the app. I also tried to use `UILabel` but it didn't work (when I click it the web didn't show)

The answer I found they didn't include the URL just `attributes.paragraphstyle`.

I don't know how to write it so I can keep the URL string also change the font/size/alignment.

```
func searchMealRecipe() {
    MealRecipeService.sharedInstance.foodID = foodID
    MealRecipeService.sharedInstance.getMealRecipe { (responseString, mealRecipeItem) in
        if responseString == "error" {
             /* popup here alerting user about error*/ 
        } else {
             self.mealRecipeItem = mealRecipeItem
             self.ingredientRecipeTitleLabel.text = (mealRecipeItem.name)?.htmlString?.string
             self.ingredientRecipeImageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: mealRecipeItem.imageURL!), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: ""))
             self.ingredientRecipeTextView.text = mealRecipeItem.ingredients?.joined(separator: "\n")
             let string = "Sounds Good! Show Me the Steps "
             let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: string, attributes:[NSAttributedString.Key.link: URL(string: "\(mealRecipeItem.link!)")!])
             self.ingredientRecipeLinkTextView.attributedText = attributedString
        }
     }
}
```

[image]

I'm using xcode10 beta and swift4.2

```
//Update(I figured it out the answer and it's working)
//the attributes accept array so I can put multiple styles in the array. 

let string = "Sounds Good! Show Me the Steps "
let style = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
style.alignment = NSTextAlignment.center
let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: string, attributes:[NSAttributedString.Key.link: URL(string: "\(mealRecipeItem.link!)")!,  NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle: style])
self.ingredientRecipeLinkTextView.attributedText = attributedString
```

[image]

Comment: you want to make the URL in the footer to be in central horizontal right ?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question.  Put the code in here, not as an image.  The image can also be showed here, not as a link.

Comment: I can't put image here because I don't have enough reputation. As you see I only have single digit for the badges.

Comment: did that for you!

Comment: Thank you :) it's funny how some people down voting my question but can't even provide the answer for me.

Answer (score 0):

you can use  NSMutableParagraphStyle

```
let style = NSMutableParagraphStyle()

 style.alignment = NSTextAlignment.center

 lbl.centerAttributedText = NSAttributedString(string: "Total Balance",attributes: [your Attributed URL Code here])
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. Do you might to edit through my code? I'm not sure what lbl.centerAttributedText is. Thanks